# Can't set up amcharts5 as a plugin in nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3, amcharts5, esmodules

I'm currently trying to use amcharts 5 in a Nuxt3 app, and had a couple of graphs working fine. However at some point amcharts has randomly stopped working and I get the following error:

```
[h3] [unhandled] H3Error: am5 is not defined
    at createError (file:///home/johnr/Code/UrbanTide/socialconnect_ukpn/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:196:15)
    at Server.nodeHandler (file:///home/johnr/Code/UrbanTide/socialconnect_ukpn/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:386:21) {
  statusCode: 500,
  fatal: false,
  unhandled: true,
  statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error'
}
```

I tried using amcharts5 according to the docs by importing it and using it in lifecycle hooks.

And initially had an issue related to ESM modules which was resolved by adding `"type" : "module"` to `package.json`. After that I made a couple of graphs and they worked fine. However shortly after writing a third graph I changed the `ssr` setting in `nuxt.config.js` to `false` and shortly after got the above error.

I've tried adding amcharts to the transpile array in the `nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt3'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    VUE_APP_AUTH_COOKIE: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_COOKIE,
    VUE_APP_ENV: process.env.VUE_APP_ENV,
    VUE_APP_SESSION_HASH: process.env.VUE_APP_SESSION_HASH,
    VUE_APP_USMART_ORIGIN: process.env.VUE_APP_USMART_ORIGIN,
    MAP_BOX_ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.MAP_BOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
  },
  css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', 'mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'],
  build: {
    transpile: ["vuetify", "@amcharts/amcharts5"]
  },
  vite: {
    define: {
      "process.env.DEBUG": false
    }
  },
  buildModules: [
    // ...
    '@pinia/nuxt',
  ],
})
```

but didn't have any joy.

I have also tried setting up a plugin:

`plugins/amCharts.client.ts`

```js
import * as am5 from "@amcharts/amcharts5";
import * as am5xy from "@amcharts/amcharts5/xy";
import * as am5radar from "@amcharts/amcharts5/radar";
import am5themes_Animated from "@amcharts/amcharts5/themes/Animated";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      am5: am5,
      am5xy: am5xy,
      am5radar: am5radar,
      am5themes_Animated: am5themes_Animated,
    }
  }
})
```

and I'm retrieving it in the component like so:

```js
const { $am5, $am5radar, $am5themes_Animated, $am5xy } = useNuxtApp()
```

Comment: Your package maybe doesn't support SSR and is client side only?

Comment: Probably a good bet. I rewrote my plugin as .client.ts buts its not resolved the problem.

Comment: Apologies dude, my bad.

Comment: So I'm an idiot. I moved a piece of the code from the component to assets because I thought it was just a static array and didn't notice it was using the am5 instance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a solved by removing a remaining piece of code calling the am5 instance as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322271/cant-set-up-amcharts5-as-a-plugin-in-nuxt-3?noredirect=1#comment129488714_73322271).
Happens to anybody!